# Ambiguity of a Cypher Match Query operation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am retrieving nodes the graph using the id. Once I get a node I am checking whether the node id is present in the list of id's I have. So, here I want to analyze the performance of the query in two ways:

```
i)Match and Retrieve
ii)Retrieve and Match
```

First Query:

```
MATCH (a{uid:4}) RETURN a
```

Second Query:

```
MATCH (a) WHERE a.uid in [1,2,3,4] RETURN a
```

In the first query, Am I retrieving the node when it match uid or else am I  retrieving a node and then checking the uid is 4 or not, if not then dropping.

In the second query, I am retrieving the node and then checking whether the node id is present in the list, if yes, then I am returning.

Ambiguity in the functionality in the first query. What exactly happens with the first query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to imply the way the query is written defines an order between the operations, but it doesn't. Cypher is a declarative language: you say what you want, it takes care of the execution in the most optimal way possible. There is absolutely no difference between

```
MATCH (a {uid: 4}) RETURN a
```

and

```
MATCH (a) WHERE uid = 4 RETURN a
```

Both queries express your need to find a node by its `uid` and the engine will do (as written) a full scan of the nodes to find those matching. If you add a label to the query, and you either have an index or a unicity constraint on `uid` for that label, then the engine will do an index lookup.

```
MATCH (a) WHERE uid IN [1, 2, 3, 4] RETURN a
```

will also do a full scan, except the `uid` will be checked against the list, whereas

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) ASSERT n.uid IS UNIQUE;
MATCH (a:Node) WHERE uid IN [1, 2, 3, 4] RETURN a
```

will do a multi-value index lookup.